# How to access html array from template on the server side (python) - Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

sorry if this question is basic but I'm a beginner :(.

I've created an array in my html template (via javascript) and user can enter multiple values for this input --- how do I then access the array from server side (python Google App Engine?)

Here's my code from html template
JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addSchool() {
    var newContent = "<input type='text' name='institution[]'></input>";
           $("#providerList").append(newContent);};
```

HTML:

```
{% for s in list %}
    <div id="institution" name="institution[]">{{s}}</div>
{% endfor %}

<div id="onemore">
    <a href='javascript:addSchool()'>Add More Institutions as Providers</a>
</div>
```

Then my server side retrieving the array - python in Google App Engine: - (which is NOT WORKING) - only retrieves 1st one:

```
mylist = self.request.get("institution[]")
```

What am I do doing wrong syntax wise to retrieve the array???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create form elements which can be submitted, like an input, or select option tags.
Or you have to create a json string and post the serialized json (javascript object) as a string.
Or you create your own string by concatenating the list elements and use it as payload for your post.

Example :

```
<form action="/addschool" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" name ="more" value="school10,school11, school12" >
    <input class="button" type="submit" id="addschool" name="addschool" value="Add a school">
</form>
```

Now you can:

```
mylist = self.request.get("more").split(',')
```